# Build Titanium SDK

Tags: build, sdk, titanium, appcelerator

I've changed some lines in 2 of the Titanium SDK files, but I'm having trouble to compile:

```
titanium_mobile/android/modules/media/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/media/TiCameraActivity.java
titanium_mobile/android/modules/media/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/media/MediaModule.java
```

This is my terminal commands:

> -bash-3.2$ cd /Users/ricardo/Downloads/titanium_mobile-master build
>   -bash-3.2$ npm install
>
> > node-ios-device@0.11.2 install /Users/ricardo/Downloads/titanium_mobile-master/node_modules/node-ios-device
> >     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> [node-ios-device] Success: "/Users/ricardo/Downloads/titanium_mobile-master/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v46-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" already installed
>   Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile
>   npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
>   npm ERR! node v4.2.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
>   npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt@1.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-clang-format@0.3.0 wants grunt@~0.4.5
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@1.0.0 wants grunt@>= 0.4.5
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-appc-js@1.0.23 wants grunt@*
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/ricardo/Downloads/titanium_mobile-master/npm-debug.log
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ricardo/Downloads/titanium_mobile-master/scons.js'
>
> -bash-3.2$ node build/scons.js build --android-ndk /opt/android-ndk --android-sdk /opt/android-sdk
>
> Building MobileSDK version 6.1.0, githash undefined
>
> -bash-3.2$ node scons.js build --android-ndk /opt/android-ndk --android-sdk /opt/android-sdk`

Comment: Why did you need to change the Ti SDK? Please let us know what features you wanted to support.

Comment: just to add the torch method in android: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4401